# Alterar campo hidden em formulario

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho dois campos hidden dentro de um formulario os mesmos devem armazenar os valores de um radio button e dos checkboxes selecionados (150 checkboxes), consegui fazer o primeiro campo hidden carregar o valor do radio button selecionado mas não consegui fazer com que o que o 2º hidden armazene os varios checkboxes marcados

```
<form class="navbar-form span7 text-center" role="search" id="search-form" action="../PHP/ValidateForm.php" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="result_type" value="videos" checked="">Videos</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="result_type" value="photos">Photos</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="result_type" value="tumblr">Tumblr</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="search_input" name="search_input" placeholder="Search" />
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="search_form_submit" value="search">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="upload-date" value="up-0" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="from" value="" />
                </form>
```

Código dos radio buttons e checkboxes:

```
<div id="right_sidebar" class="col-md-2"><!-- START Right Sidebar -->
<div class="row">
    <h4>Upload Date</h4>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="upload-date" value="up-0" checked="checked">ANYTIME</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="upload-date" value="up-1">Today</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="upload-date" value="up-2">This Week</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="upload-date" value="up-3">This Month</label>
    </div>
    <h4>From</h4>
    <div id="sites-list">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="site[]" value="site-0" checked="checked">ANYONE</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="site[]" value="site-1">Site</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="site[]" value="site-2">Site</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="site[]" value="site-3">Site</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Código que funciona somente para inserção do valor do radio button ao 1º hidden

```
$('input[name=upload-date]').change(function(){
    $('#search-form > input[name=upload-date]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Confirmando O 1º campo hidden que armazana o resultado da seleção de radios está funcionando, o 2º que armazenaria todos o checkboxes não.

Comment: Você vai colocar somente um valor, dos 150, em um input?

Comment: sim são 150 opções onde o usuario poderá escolher de 0 até 150 opções, eles não são autoexcludentes então ele poderá escolher todas

Comment: Então poderá ficar no input algo como: up-0 up-1 up-2...?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Qual o motivo de colocar os valores nestes input's? Quando o formulário for submetido você irá receber os input's `radio` e `checkbox`.

Comment: @Rafael o input com value=up-0 up-1 up-2 são radio buttons então só haverá um, Obs: o primeiro campo hidden esta funcionando

Comment: hummmm. Então os os radio darão um valor para o input no name="upload-date"?? É só isso que você quer nessa etapa?

Comment: Outra coisa, não é que só ta funcionando um, não ta funcionando nada, pois você setou um value="up-0", no hidden. kkk

Comment: @Oeslei estou querendo colocar os valores marcados nos checkboxes dentro do 2º campo hidenn

Comment: @Rafael quando clico em outro radio é atribuido o valor dele ao campo hidden

Comment: Entendi. :)-----

Comment: SERÃO QUANTOS RADIO? Somente esses?

Comment: @Rafael serão 4 Radios por outro lado será 150 chekboxes (tem um css aplicado pra ter uma barra de rolagem)

Comment: @RicardoHenrique, Veja se este é o caminho. Retirei o hidden, para conferência, e somente fiz os do radio:

http://jsfiddle.net/voyhzec4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É o seguinte, você está duplicando os input's através do atributo `name`. Você deve ter os dois input's do tipo `hidden` com names diferentes dos radios e checkboxes.

```
<!-- veja que alterei o campo name do upload-date -->
<input type="hidden" name="uploadDate" value="up-0" />
<input type="hidden" name="from" value="" />
```

Também sugiro colocar um `id` nestes dois input's para facilitar a seleção no script.

```
<input type="hidden" name="uploadDate" id="uploadDate" value="up-0" />
<input type="hidden" name="from" id="from" value="" />
```

---

```
$('input[name=upload-date]').change(function() {
    // apenas modifiquei o seletor
    $('#search-form #uploadDate').val($(this).val());
});

// não sou muito inclinado a usar seletores para campos com
// name indicando um array, por isso deixo uma alternativa
$('#sites-list :checkbox').change(function() {
    // array para os checkboxes selecionados
    var arrSel = [];
    $('#sites-list :checkbox').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // adiciona ao array
            arrSel.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    // junta tudo no input desejado
    $('#from').val(arrSel.join(','));
    // o input ficará com os valores separados por vírgula
    // ex: site-1, site-2
}
```

Comment: ,@Oeslei poderia trocar ('#sites-list :checkbox) por (input[name=site])? funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Funciona colocando este seletor? Você pode editar minha pergunta se quiser. Eu nunca uso seletores pelo atributo `name` quando os mesmos são arrays. Normalmente utilizo o `id` =)

Comment: OK, obrigado pela resposta. a proposito com <input type="hidden" name="upload-ate" value="up-0" /> estava funcionando mesmo com o name deste hidden igual ao name dos radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

Esta query devolve o *primeiro* input abaixo de search-form:

```
$('#search-form > input[name=upload-date]')
```

Precisaria de algo como:

```
$('#search-form input[name=upload-date]')
```

Comment: Olá @RicardoPeres, o input[name=upload-date] so tenho um input com name=upload-date os outros inputs possuem name diferente

Comment: Mas não é isso que está no código que submeteu: <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="upload-date" value="up-1">Today</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="upload-date" value="up-2">This Week</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="upload-date" value="up-3">This Month</label>
    </div>